# How to remove re-occurring lines with specific pattern in Visual Studio solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I have a very old `C#` based web application in `Visual Studio 2019`.
There are hundreds of files in the solution with probably thousands of lines for logging.
We have recently realized that we don't need this logging any more and so I need to remove these statements from the code.
So my question - Is there any way to remove these logging statements from the code in one shot using `Find/Replace` or any other clean up tool?

The statements look like this -

```
_logger.LogInformation("Something happened here");
```

Comment: Close voter: just wonder what Stack Overflow guideline this question doesn't meet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use (a limited form of) regular expressions when searching and replacing in Visual Studio.

Go to `Edit | Find and Replace | Replace in Files` to open the dialog, and then select *Use regular expressions*.

Then your target text should be something like:

`(^|\s)*_logger\.LogInformation\(.*\);`

And the replacement would be an empty string. Click *Replace All* and it will probably replace most of them. However, this sort of thing can be fraught with peril, so you should check carefully what changes it makes!